# Simple validation is also not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

This is my simple html code. I included javascript inside this html file.I would like to perform validation on name like no empty field and data format validation but it is not working. Can some one please help me to get rid of this

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Aptitude Competition Online</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function validate()
  {  
  var nam = document.forms[0].name.value; 
    if(nam == "") 
     { 
         alert("Name should be filled out"); 
         document.getElementById("name").focus;
         return false;
     } 
    else {  
         return true; 
         } 
   }
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header1">
<font id="font1">Aptitude Quiz</font>
</div>
<div id="bgr">
<div id="emal">
<font style="position:absolute;top:16px;left:100px;font-size:20px;">Welcome     to Aptitude Quiz</font><br><br><br
<form name="form">
 Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
 <input name="Participate" type="button" value="Participate"  onClick="validate()" >
 </form>

  </div>
 </div>
  <div id="footer">
   Contact Us : gmail@name.com 
   </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in your HTML code. You forgot to close a `<br>` tag before `<form name='form'>`

Also, "focus" is a method, not a property. I have added that as well

Here is the corrected code.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Aptitude Competition Online</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var nam = document.forms[0].name.value;
            if (nam == "") {
                alert("Name should be filled out");
                document.getElementById("name").focus();
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header1">
        <font id="font1">Aptitude Quiz</font>
    </div>
    <div id="bgr">
        <div id="emal">
            <font style="position:absolute;top:16px;left:100px;font-size:20px;">Welcome     to Aptitude Quiz</font>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br> <form name="form"> Name :
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input name="Participate" type="button" value="Participate" onClick="validate()">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Contact Us : gmail@name.com
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The <br> tag before "<form name="form">"

Comment: Yes. The HTML parser will not consider your opening <form> tag to be valid, since the <br tag is not closed yet. Therefore document.forms[0] will be undefined.

Comment: i forget put () for "focus" method. Tq bro u helped me to make my project. Tq alot

Comment: can i have ur facebook or linkd in id please...,

Comment: @VinodChowdaryDirishala No problem man. Would be really grateful if you marked my answer as correct :-)

Comment: @VinodChowdaryDirishala Thanks